# TestNG Failed Confguration @AfterTest

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

@After Method failed configuration error appears when i run this code.

```
 package automationFramework;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import pageobjects.LoginPageObj;

    public class TestCase_POF {

        WebDriver driver;
        LoginPageObj lpo;

        @BeforeMethod
        public void beforeMethod() {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "h:\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.get("https://slingshotinsights.com/");

        }

        @Test
        public void test() {
            lpo = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPageObj.class);
            lpo.LoginAction("johnmc", "k12345678");
            System.out.println("User has been Logged-in Successfully");

        }

        @AfterMethod
        public void afterMethod() {

            driver.quit();

        }
    }
```

Below is the output of the eclipse console
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod afterMethod
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Please Help me, thank you

Comment: Not very clear from your question though. But seems like the `driver` is null when the execution reached the `@AfterMethod`. Is this all code you have? and does the driver in the `@BeforeMethod` gets set correctly?

Comment: try @AfterSuite annotation tag instead

Answer (score 1):

yes, driver is null.

In

```
  @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
    //use
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

as already declared class level WebDriver driver;

Comment: I did this but now @Test test() method is not calling. BeforeMethod beforeMethod calls, it skips Test test() methods and Jumps over to AfterMethod afterMethod

Comment: try by using static WebDriver driver;